# How do I give my soldiers armour in Mount and Blade Warband?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I'm fairly new to Mound and Blade Warband, but I have watched youtubers play and they always have an option to give their soldiers (Just normal ones) the rest of the loot and equip them after the end of a battle When i win a battle i can only equip weapons for myself and the rest is sold i can only guess? Is it a mod i need to download or what?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible in the default Mount and Blade: Warband. There are several mods which provide such functionality, though i think most mods, for example [Floris](http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php/topic,148140.0.html), only have automatic distribution of loot to your heroes, not your troops.

I can't think of any mod that allows full customization of troops but since there are quite a lot of mods, you might find what you are looking for in the [Mod list](http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php/board,165.0.html)

Comment: There are mods,Floris being one of them, that let's you pick armor to change the appearance of soldiers as well as a few weapons but its still from a stock selection that you can't change

Comment: Are you sure this isn't possible? I remember being able to see my soldiers stats and weapons, but I might be mistaken?

Comment: @Lyrion in the mod its possible.  You ask them to see their equipment and it takes you to a equipment screen where you can pick and choose a few items from a stock list.  This may only work with specific soldier types, but I know for sure this works for the freelancer mercenaries.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to customise the equipment of your heroes, either by talking to them individually through the party screen or in some mods, like *Floris*, you also have the option of auto-updating it from a communal equipment pool.

As far as I know, none of the mods allow you to customise the equipment of your regular troops, although you can do this through *Morgh's Editor*, as has been mentioned in a post above.

You can also create your own Knighthood Order in *Prophecy of Pendor*, and you have the ability to customise the troops that are produced, both in terms of equipment and training.

If you feel that the troops in *Warband* are a little limited, then you can also use a mod like *Floris* to expands upon the troop trees of all factions. That might give you more of the experience you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.taleworlds.com/?topic=105928.0

Here is the way to change nearly Everything on warband.

I Think all moders are using it.